# Interpolating colors in PHP

Tags: php, html, colors, interpolation

I'm a C++ programmer who recently started delving into web development with PHP, Javascript and HTML. Currently I'm having trouble with something that should be very simple, but isn't working as I expected...

```
function interpolateColor($corA, $corB, $lerp)
{
$redA = $corA & 0xFF0000;
$greenA = $corA & 0x00FF00;
$blueA = $corA & 0x0000FF;
$redB = $corB & 0xFF0000;
$greenB = $corB & 0x00FF00;
$blueB = $corB & 0x0000FF;

$redC = $redA + (($redB - $redA) * $lerp);
$greenC = $greenA + (($greenB - $greenA) * $lerp);
$blueC = $blueA + (($blueB - $blueA) * $lerp);

return $redC | $greenC | $blueC;
}
```

I've been trying to use this function to make the rows of a HTML table different colors based on the value of a "Priority" column, that goes from 0 to 10 and is divided by 10 to form the "lerpAmount" (0-1) variable.

```
$cor = interpolateColor(0xFF0000, 0x0000FF, $lerpAmount);

<tr bgcolor="<?=$cor?>">
```

However the colors I get don't look like a Red-Blue interpolation... It starts blueish, then only one of the rows is green, then it becomes pink and interpolates to some form of brown, before turning dark blue again, which makes me think that something's very wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i would suggest reduce the lerpamount and try out the result.

Comment: Your $redC, $greenC and $blueC values will all be float after the multiplication by $lerp, so you're ORing a series of floats together for your return... You probably want to cast each to int again before doing that: e.g. `$redC = (int) $redA + (($redB - $redA) * $lerp);`

Comment: Some values are negative also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do a bitwise AND operation between the result colors and the masks:

```
$redC = $redA + (($redB - $redA) * $lerp) & 0xFF0000;         // Only Red
$greenC = $greenA + (($greenB - $greenA) * $lerp) & 0x00FF00; // Only Green
$blueC = $blueA + (($blueB - $blueA) * $lerp) & 0x0000FF;     // Only Blue
```

to get the correct values for RGB, and then to return the color in hexadecimal you must convert it using:

```
$result = dechex($redC | $greenC | $blueC);
return str_pad($result, 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

(the str_pad is to add leading zeros to the returned color).

Answer (score -1):

The problem you face here is one of underflow. I think. I don't know if that's the right word XD

Anyway!

Let's say you're trying to get the colour that is exactly 50% of the way between red and black.

So you're interpolating 0xFF0000 and 0x000000. You would expect either 0x800000 or 0x7F0000 as the result, right?

But that's not what you get. Instead you get 0x7F8000, which is kind of a dull yellow.

Personally, I would do something like this:

```
$rgbA = array(
    ($corA & 0xFF0000) >> 16,
    ($corA & 0x00FF00) >> 8,
    ($corA & 0x0000FF)
);
$rgbB = array(
    ($corB & 0xFF0000) >> 16,
    ($corB & 0x00FF00) >> 8,
    ($corB & 0x0000FF)
);
$rgbC = array_map(
    function($a,$b) use ($lerp) {return round($a+($b-$a)*$lerp);},
    $rgbA, $rgbB
);
// if you want a number:
return $rgbC[0]<<16 | $rgbC[1]<<8 | $rgbC[2];
// if you want an HTML hex code:
return sprintf("#%02X%02X%02X",$rgbC[0],$rgbC[1],$rgbC[2]);
```

Comment: Why to change all the code? The original one is right, adding a simple bitwise AND operation with the right masks it's functional. The array_map is unnecessary, the bits shifting too!